# Add a custom revision name or change a default revision name on Cloud Run (GCP)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-run, revision

I ran the command below referring to [Shipping the public editor service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/secure-services#shipping-frontend) in [Securing Cloud Run services tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/secure-services):

```
gcloud run deploy editor --image gcr.io/myproject-242723/editor \
  --service-account editor-identity \
  --set-env-vars EDITOR_UPSTREAM_RENDER_URL=https://renderer-6cl2nkfhva-an.a.run.app \
  --allow-unauthenticated
```

Then, **the revision "editor-00001-xaj"** is created as shown below:

[image]

Now, I want to add **the custom revision name "editor-v1.0.0"** to a revision when creating it or change **the default revision name "editor-00001-xaj"** to **"editor-v1.0.0"**. Are there any ways to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as I researched, there are no ways to change a revision name but you can add a custom revision name to a revision when creating it.

With this command below:

```
gcloud run deploy <service>
```

And the flag below, you can add **a custom revision name** to a revision when creating it:

```
--revision-suffix <revision_suffix>
```

But **your custom revision name "editor-v1.0.0"** is not allowed for a revision name because a revision name only allows **lowercase letters, numbers and hyphen "-" and must begin with a letter and cannot end with hyphen "-" and the maximum length is 63 characters**. So **"editor-v1.0.0"** contains **period "."** which is not allowed for a revision name. So if you really want to add **"editor-v1.0.0"** to a revision, change it to **"editor-v1-0-0"**.

Now, you can add **the custom revision name "editor-v1-0-0"** to a revision when creating it so you need to put **only the suffix part "v1-0-0"** to the flag as shown below:

```
--revision-suffix v1-0-0
```

Then, including the flag above, I run the full command as shown below:

```
gcloud run deploy editor --image gcr.io/myproject-242723/editor \
  --service-account editor-identity \
  --set-env-vars EDITOR_UPSTREAM_RENDER_URL=https://renderer-6cl2nkfhva-an.a.run.app \
  --allow-unauthenticated \
  --revision-suffix v1-0-0 // Here
```

Now, **the custom revision name "editor-v1-0-0"** is added to a revision when creating it as shown below:

[image]

In addition, if you run the full command mistakenly putting **the whole name "editor-v1-0-0"** to **the flag "--revision-suffix"** as shown below:

```
gcloud run deploy editor --image gcr.io/myproject-242723/editor \
  --service-account editor-identity \
  --set-env-vars EDITOR_UPSTREAM_RENDER_URL=https://renderer-6cl2nkfhva-an.a.run.app \
  --allow-unauthenticated \
  --revision-suffix editor-v1-0-0 // Here
```

**The custom revision name "editor-editor-v1-0-0"** is added to a revision when creating it as shown below so be careful not to mistakenly put **the whole name "editor-v1-0-0"** to **the flag "--revision-suffix"**:

[image]

In addition again, if you run the full command mistakenly putting **the suffix part "v1.0.0"** with **period "."** instead of **hyphen "-"** to **the flag --revision-suffix"** as shown below:

```
gcloud run deploy editor --image gcr.io/myproject-242723/editor \
  --service-account editor-identity \
  --set-env-vars EDITOR_UPSTREAM_RENDER_URL=https://renderer-6cl2nkfhva-an.a.run.app \
  --allow-unauthenticated \
  --revision-suffix v1.0.0 // Here
```

You'll get this error below so be careful not to mistakenly put **the suffix part "v1.0.0"** with **period "."** instead of **hyphen "-"** to **the flag --revision-suffix"**:

> ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) metadata.name: Resource name must use only
> lowercase letters, numbers and '-'. Must begin with a letter and
> cannot end with a '-'. Maximum length is 63 characters.

Comment: Thank you. And do you how know to set the revision-suffix tag while using gcloud replace command?